# Get object of case class from regex match

Tags: regex, scala

i'm working on scraping data from a webpage with scala regex-es, but i encountered problem with parsing result to object of some case class-es.

In following snippet i managed to scrape all the data, but i have no clue how to parse 3 elements from an iterator. I thought about something like:

```
val a :: b :: c :: _ = result.group(0).iDontKnowWha
```

Any ideas what can i do?

```
import model.FuneralSchedule
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import scala.io.Source
 
var date = "2015-05-05"
val source = Source.fromURL("http://zck.krakow.pl/?pageId=16&date=" + date).mkString
val regex = "(?s)<table>.+?(Cmentarz.+?)<.+?</table>".r
var thing: List[FuneralSchedule] = List()
var jsonFeed: List[Funeral] = List()
val regMatcher = "("
 
case class Funeral(hour: String, who: String, age: String) {
  override def toString: String = {
    "Cos"
  }
}
 
//implicit val format = Json.format[Funeral]
val out = regex.findAllIn(source).matchData foreach { table =>
  thing ::= FuneralSchedule(table.group(1), clearStrings(table.group(0)))
  """<tr\s?>.+?</\s?tr>""".r.findAllIn(clearStrings(table.group(0))).matchData foreach { tr =>
    //TODO: Naprawic bo szlak trafia wydajnosc
    val temp = """<td\s?>.+?</\s?td>""".r.findAllIn(tr.group(0)).matchData.foreach {
      elem => println(elem)
    }
    //println(Json.toJson(thingy))
  }
  println("Koniec tabeli")
}
thing
//Json.toJson(jsonFeed)
println(removeMarkers("<td > <td> Marian Debil </ td>"))
def removeMarkers(s: String) = {
  s.replaceAll( """(</?\s?td\s?>)""", "")
}
def clearStrings(s: String) = {
  val regex = "((class=\".+?\")|(id=\".+?\")|(style=\".+?\")|(\\n))"
  s.replaceAll(regex, "")
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem place in this example exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it would be converting it to a `Stream` and matching it using stream's operators like this:

```
val a #:: b #:: c #:: _ = """([a-z]){1}""".r.findAllIn("a b c").toStream
```

then `a`, `b` and `c` is what you're looking for

Comment: Any ideas how to avoid getting exception when getting "<td ></td>                <td></td>"

Comment: You should check the length first or use methods like `headOption`. Syntax would be more verbose though